# Publishing .NET 8 Razor Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-toolkit

I'm trying to publish my .NET 8 Razor Web-application to an elastic beanstalk instance using the AWS Toolkit in Visual Studios. However when I try to publish to the instance it keeps failing and after inspecting the logfiles I see

`web: /bin/sh: ./ApplicationName: cannot execute binary file`

from the "web.stdout.log" logs. I cannot find this binary file it is referring too.

Any help on potential configurations missed would be much appreciated.

Comment: I seem to have fixed this, however I'm not 100% sure what I did. One this that might have fixed it was clicking re-build and clean to remove all the unneeded files. But unsure.